# Based on EMI RL circuit.... time constant

Tags: time-constant

How is the time constant for an LR circuit is determined in the case of charging, where one resistor is connected in parallel and another resistor is connected series to an inductor. [image]

Comment: Show the circuit you have in mind, because it depends on where the parallel resistor is located (in parallel with the source or in parallel with the inductor).  If it is the latter, then Andy’s answer below is what you want.

Comment: Sir i have added it please check now

Comment: Please check now

Comment: Thanks for adding the picture. It is clear now, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your upper resistor is in parallel with the ideal voltage source, it will not be part of the time constant for the inductor transient.  You can ignore it as if it’s not even there.

Comment: Sir why we are neglecting the above resistance?

Comment: But what u have said is the same on my book solution

Comment: Sir.... please post an image of what circuit mr. Andy has explained.... iam confused with that

Comment: You are welcome.  Andy (I think) was thinking your upper resistor was in parallel with just the inductor.